# Is there a way to submit sampler2D and a texture object into different slots in OpenGL-GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to do separate bindings for texture and the sampler.
Like the code below:

```c
layout(set = 1, binding = 1) uniform texture2D SurfaceTexture;
layout(set = 1, binding = 2) uniform sampler SurfaceSampler;
```

But I get this error when linking the shaders:

```
error C7548: 'layout(set)' requires "#extension GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl : enable" before use
```

I'm trying to create an API-agnostic renderer which will also support DX11-DX12 and Vulkan so I should be committing texture and samplers in different slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to do separate bindings for texture and the sampler.

OpenGL doesn't want you to. So you can't.

GL doesn't allow you to do the separate texture/sampler thing (there isn't even an extension for it). D3D *requires* you to do the separate texture/sampler thing. Vulkan will let you do either.

So you're going to have to pick a side. Or you're going to have to make your renderer translate one to the other.

Also, OpenGL doesn't have descriptor sets, so `layout(set = #` is meaningless.